# hide already used categories from the list php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that inserts the data in a table of the db, I have been asked to hide from the options of the select, all the categories that have already been used.

query:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO Cat_documenti (codice_cat_doc, titolo_cat_doc, desc_cat_doc, id_struttura) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['cod_cat'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString(inputControl(docUpdate(strtoupper($_POST['titolo_cat']))), "text"),
    GetSQLValueString(inputControl($_POST['desc_cat']), "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($id_az, "int")
);

//dwthai.com($database_riskmanagement, $riskmanagement);
$Result1 = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($riskmanagement));
$id_inserito = mysqli_insert_id();
createLog($_COOKIE['cod_operatore'], $insertSQL, $id_inserito);
```

how can you hide a result in php?

the value in the db is: `cod_cat`

html:

```
<select name="cod_cat" id="cod_cat" class="form-control m-bot15" required>
    <option value="">Selezionare</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="H">H</option>
    <option value="I">I</option>
    <option value="J">J</option>
    <option value="K">K</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="N">N</option>
    <option value="O">O</option>
    <option value="P">P</option>
    <option value="Q">Q</option>
    <option value="R">R</option>
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="T">T</option>
    <option value="U">U</option>
    <option value="V">V</option>
    <option value="W">W</option>
    <option value="X">X</option>
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    <option value="Z">Z</option>
</select>
```

i know one possibility its implement a variable to control, but i don t know to hide a value

example:

```
$CONTROLLA = mysqli_query($VARIABLE_OF_MY_CONNECTION,"SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION");
$SE_IL_RISULTATO_IMMESSO=mysqli_num_rows($CONTROLLA);

if($SE_IL_RISULTATO_IMMESSO==0)  {
    $connessione->query("INSERT INTO TABLE ……”);
    $POSITIVE_MESSAGE = ‘ECHO WHAT YOU WANT’;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your problem. Please check below code and implement it

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT category from categories group by category";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



$selected = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $selected[] = $row['category'];
}

echo '<select>';
foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    if(!in_array($letter, $selected)){
        echo '<option value="'.$letter.'">'.$letter.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't edit existing html code with PHP you either could outpout some Javascript code with PHP, which removes the used options, or simply display only the non used options with PHP. So, you would do something like this:

```html
<!-- Your HTML code -->

<?php
//Do your database query, if requested
?>

<!-- Build the select element: -->
<select name="cod_cat" id="cod_cat" class="form-control m-bot15" required>
    <option value="">Selezionare</option>

<?php
//Here you would display the available options like this:
echo "<option value="A">A</option>";
...

//The selected values will be in the variable $_POST['cod_cat']
//So, you need to iterate over all your values (A-Z) and remove the values in $_POST['cod_cat'] 
foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    if(!in_array($letter, $_POST['cod_cat'])){
        echo '<option value="'.$letter.'">'.$letter.'</option>';
    }
}
?>

</select>


<!-- Your HTML code -->
```

Comment: the problem is, that the condition is always true, because I'm telling him about echo, all the categories, I didn't solve my problem, I just wrote it differently

Comment: What condition is always true? I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: in the sense that if having static values ​​in html, if I do echo with all my options, I will always have all my options and not just those that are not present in the database

Comment: Thats why you only display all values, which are NOT IN THE QUERY you performed before.

Comment: and how could I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: how to make the iterate values?

Comment: //Do your database query, if requested? use Distinct?

Comment: I added the loop (untested)